# Disable aria logs mariaDB

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB is suddenly logging aria_log.0000xx files. These files are (by default) 1.1GB but I keep getting these files every few minutes, eventually running out of diskspace. There are a lot of transactions going on so that might explain the amount of files but I can't find a way to disable it.

It's not binary logging. Log_bin is set to off and when trying to show the binary logs "You are not using binary logging" message appears.

The only thing I can find about aria_logs is how to change the default size and how to purge them.  Is there a way to disable these files from logging?

Comment: Removing [tag:mysql] tag because the aria storage engine is not used in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the config option [aria_log_purge_type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-system-variables/#aria_log_purge_type). If its value is set to "at_flush" then the logs are kept until you FLUSH ENGINE LOGS.

The default value is "immediate" which I assume means to drop the log files as soon as they are no longer needed. But the documentation is pretty sparse about this option.

If they are not dropped immediately, you can purge them. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flush/ says:

> `FLUSH ENGINE LOGS` will delete all unneeded Aria redo logs.

I'm not a MariaDB user, so that's all I know about this. I suggest to read the documentation. Perhaps there's more information in blogs or articles about MariaDB.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. I can succesfully flush the logs and engine logs but 0 rows are affected. The aria_logs are still there. There nothing I can find about this in the documentation. Only about purging and flushing but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Then I suppose Aria believes those logs are still needed. I agree the information about this is pretty sparse. I suggest getting a support contract with MariaDB and then you can ask them for more direct help.